# How to remove duplicate x-axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize babynames dataset, the dataset itself has been merged from separate files for each year (from 1880 to 2017), as a result it contains duplicate values for "year" column. Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

colorPallete <- c("orange", "blue")

ggplot(dataset, aes(x=year, y = births, colour = sex, group = sex)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="line") + theme(legend.position = "right")

ggtitle("Total births by sex and year") + scale_colour_manual(values = colorPallete)
```

Here's the sample of my data:
dropbox.com/s/4sgrqp7o3aza4gn/dataset.csv?dl=0

Here's what I currently have: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZrqK.jpg

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyRmd.jpg

Comment: It looks like year is stored as a character, based on the ggplot output. Perhaps use `x = as.numeric(year)`? It will be easier to help you if you can provide in your question a sample of your data (including what format its stored in) by using `dput(head(dataset))`. A screenshot of your data doesn't give potential helpers a way to work with your data efficiently.

Comment: "x=as.numeric(year)" solves the problem of duplicate labels, but x-axis labels don't relate to actual data stored in "year" column. Here's the graph after this tweak: https://i.imgur.com/tlwKxUa.jpg. Here's the sample of my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sgrqp7o3aza4gn/dataset.csv?dl=0. And seems like year is stored as a character: https://i.imgur.com/6HVJkTS.jpg.

Comment: Aha. Again, please update your question to include a sample of your data by using `dput(head(dataset))`, as opposed to linking to an external site (should I trust it? will it be a working link 2 years from now?). I suspect the year is stored as a factor, but I'm still just guessing. Try `x = as.numeric(as.character(year))`.

Comment: I updated the question, ```x  = as.numeric(as.character(year))``` outputs the desired result. Here's the output:  https://i.imgur.com/I4Yjg18.jpg. Thank you for help!